# Bigcommerce throwing 403 error even with all scope using postman

Tags: api, get, bigcommerce

Trying to test bigcommerce api but its giving 403 error "You don't have a required scope to access the endpoint". Here the link i used to test and also a pic:

```
https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/store_xxxx/v3/catalog/products
```

[image]

And here's all the scopes I have allowed in bigcommerce

[image]

Answer (score 1):

needed to remove "store_". Its working now.