# How to solve in postman response you don't have a required scope to access the endpoint

Tags: php, json, bigcommerce

I have a test account in Bigcommerce eCommerce and I want to get a response it's not coming I don't know what is loop falls here because I have to make an API store account and I have X-Auth-Client, the x-Auth-Token key also showing some error 403 in postman I to get a proper response via postman for API. I have seen many examples but didn't get proper solutions.
for example, I see here
[Bigcommerce throwing 403 error even with all scope using postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918566/bigcommerce-throwing-403-error-even-with-all-scope-using-postman)
but didn't get a solution in a proper way.

I am getting in response how to solve it

```
{
    "status": 403,
    "title": "You don't have a required scope to access the endpoint",
    "type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/api-status-codes",
    "errors": {}
}
```

This is my keys or authentications in the header
I have a response code is that in postman how to solve that issue and get a proper response
[image]

I have created a store in Bigcommerce

[image]

All the data I have put as showing in the above figures but I am didn't find out why not showing data in response to any issue resolve it. I have already taken time to complete the task so resolve it if any issue is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, I can see that the censored part of your URI in Postman seems to be too long for a regular BigCommerce store hash.

You don't want your store hash to be *store_abcd1234* or *store-abcd1234*, the URI should look like this:

`GET https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/abcd1234/v3/catalog/products`

The `abcd1234` portion of the URI can be found in the URL of your BigCommerce control panel. Example: https://store-**abcd1234**.mybigcommerce.com/

I get the same 403 errors when I try to make a request to an incorrect store hash path parameter.